# Different color for lines

Tags: graphics

please help me. I want to paint every line different color, tried many ways, but they don't works. Thank you.

```
Animate[
 Graphics[{{Style [
     Line[{{{0, 0}, {3 Cos[x], 3 Sin[x]}}, {{0, 0}, {3 Cos[x - x/10], 
         3 Sin[x - x/10]}}}], {Red, Blue}] }}, Axes -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}} ], {x, 0, 2 π}]
```

[image]

Comment: Structure your `Graphics` command like `Graphics[{color1, line1, color2, line2}]`

Comment: `Animate[
 Graphics[
  Thread[{{Red, Blue}, 
    Line /@ {{{0, 0}, {3 Cos[x], 3 Sin[x]}}, {{0, 
        0}, {3 Cos[x - x/10], 3 Sin[x - x/10]}}}}], Axes -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]`

Answer (score 4):

The simple solution as already given in the comments is to split the `Line` expression and interleave color directives:

```
Animate[Graphics[{{Red, Line[{{0, 0}, {3 Cos[x], 3 Sin[x]}}]},
   {Blue, Line[{{0, 0}, {3 Cos[x - x/10], 3 Sin[x - x/10]}}]}}, Axes -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}], {x, 0, 2 π}]
```

In the case of more line segments there can be an advantage to preserving a single `Line` expression as this is typically rendered faster.  To make that work with individual segment colors you can use [`VertexColors`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexColors.html) and specify the color for each end of each line segment:

```
Animate[Graphics[
  Line[{{{0, 0}, {3 Cos[x], 3 Sin[x]}}, {{0, 0}, {3 Cos[x - x/10], 
      3 Sin[x - x/10]}}}, VertexColors -> {{Red, Red}, {Blue, Blue}}], Axes -> True,
   PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}], {x, 0, 2 π}]
```

[image]

A Larger example:

```
colors = ({#, #} & /@ RandomColor[50]);

Animate[
  Graphics[
    Line[{#, {0, 0}} & /@ CirclePoints[{1, x}, 50], VertexColors -> colors]
  ],
  {x, 0, Pi/5}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I'm having a slightly different problem. I've look everywhere but until now I couldn't finish this task. I've tried colordata,colorlist,vertexcolors, and several other techniques but it is still not working with my data. I want to make that the color on my curve changes for every iteration. Let say it has 3 iterations that will produce 3 different line, I want it to produce different color for each line. Can anyone help me?

Comment: @NKamaru Please post a new question with as much information as possible.  Describe exactly what you want, include pictures, and show the code you are starting with.